# Show a node through a view in the node panel layout

Tags: views, panels

In Drupal 7, I use the node template panel layout to display any node/contents.
is there is a way that I can show a node through a view in the node panel layout for the particular node?

i.e : I am having 10 contents displaying on my home page belonging to "vehicle" content type.,
once I click on a content it should take me to the particular page listing all the details about it through a view.

I guess I need to pass some arguments here when creating the view/panels, but not sure where exactly i should do that..

Thank you

Comment: OK guys! just did as I was playing with both panels and views
1. Created a view added a contextual filters for "nid" 2.when adding the view to the panel layout I simply clicked "send arguments" this gave me the expected results. thanks for me ;)

Comment: could you please answer it and check as solved..not as a comment so another people can see it. The comments sometimes are missed.